# encode in encode

Tags: cipher, formation-of-numbers

Today, a cryptic message was received by Area 51:

```
Bananatexteismarvellous605185682252125223459314283216133301

2
```

The staff managed to figure out that some 2 digit number was being encoded, but they couldn’t find what it was. Can you help them?

> Title hint